# Value not inserted into database when submitted from html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

HTML Page appears on calling index.php
While submitting the value, no error is shown and page is refreshed. However no value appears in the database table.
No error is shown as well. 
Please suggest solution.

Database name : cardb
Table name : car

PHP CODE

```
    <?php

include('index.html');
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','cardb');
if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
 $seat_value=$_POST['seat'];
 $fuel_value=$_POST['fuel'];
 $class_value=$_POST['class'];
 $body_value=$_POST['bodystyle'];
 $sql = "INSERT INTO car (`seat`,fuel,class,bodystyle)
           VALUES ('$seat_value','$fuel_value','$class_value','$body_value')";  
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) 
    {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
    } 
    else 
    {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }


$conn->close();
?>
```

HTML

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="inputs">
    <div id="specs" class="content-section-b" style="border-top: 0">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center wrap_title">
                <h2>Specification</h2>
                <p class="lead" style="margin-top:0">Tell us what you are looking for</p>

            </div>

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img class="rotate" src="img/icon/tweet.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                  <h3>Fuel</h3>


                    <select id="dropdown1" name="fuel">
                      <option  value="any" selected >No Preference</option>
                      <option value="petrol">Petrol</option>
                      <option value="diesel">Diesel</option>
                    </select>
                 </div>

                 <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">

                 </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img class="rotate" src="img/icon/tweet.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                  <h3>Seating</h3>


                    <select id="dropdown2" name="seat">
                      <option  value="any" selected >No Preference</option>
                      <option value="seat45">4/5</option>
                      <option value="seat67">6/7</option>
                      <option value="seat8">8</option>
                    </select>
                 </div> 
            </div> <!-- row -->

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img class="rotate" src="img/icon/tweet.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                  <h3>Body Style</h3>


                    <select id="dropdown3" name="bodystyle">
                      <option  value="any" selected >No Preference</option>
                      <option value="sedan">Sedan</option>
                      <option value="hatchback">Hatchback</option>
                      <option value="mpv">MPV</option>
                      <option value="suv">SUV</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 wow fadeInDown text-center">
                  <img class="rotate" src="img/icon/tweet.svg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                  <h3>Class</h3>


                    <select id="dropdown4" name="class">
                      <option  value="any" selected >No Preference</option>
                      <option value="economy">Economy</option>
                      <option value="executive">Executive</option>
                      <option value="buisness">Buisness</option>
                     </select>
                 </div>
            </div> <!-- row -->


        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="specs" vertical-align: top;>
<!-- SUBMIT --> <center> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary view" form="inputs" value="Submit">Submit</button> </center>
    </div>
```

Comment: if you echo the query, what will be the value of it? try echo $sql before executing the query.

Comment: Question is: *"How"* are you accessing that file? As `http://localhost/index.html` or `file:///index.html` or As `http://localhost/index.php` or `file:///index.php`? is a webserver/php/mysql installed and running properly? I can't see how your code would fail. However, MySQL will fail *silently* if the columns' lengths are too short. Look at your HTML source to see what is revealed and run a var_dump().

Comment: Not getting connection error and else part error than please add Php error_reporting()

Comment: @devpro localhost/index.php
https://postimg.org/image/ul4xpq2yb/b9d943ab/

PS : Making the submit button inside form did not work

Comment: @devpro Thanks those functions pointed out the errors. It was with the wrong field type specified in the DB. Thanks! Cheers! :D

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Besides [what I wrote in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426611/value-not-inserted-into-database-when-submitted-from-html-page/39426707#comment66177067_39426611) about how you're accessing that file (which does matter):

Your `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary view" form="inputs" value="Submit">Submit</button>` **is outside** the `<form...>...</form>` tags.

- Place it **"inside"** them.

On an added note; your code is open to an SQL injection. Use a prepared statement.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement